# Process UITableViewController with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have problem with `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
 (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /*if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    NSObject *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];*/
```

`if (!self.travelViewController) {
    self.travelViewController = [[TravelViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TravelViewController" bundle:nil];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.travelViewController animated:YES];
}`

`pushViewController` use in `UIViewController` but `travelViewController` inherits from `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Please help me right statement change  for pushViewController that it use in UITableViewController

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll give it a shot, despite the lack of a question. I assume that you're using the generic code which is commented out, and changed it to the second version.

If so, it looks fine, except that you haven't given the travelViewController any information about which "travel" to show. Usually, didSelectRow is called when the user taps on a row, indicating that they want to interact with that particular row.